# mod_rewrite changes MIME types .css/.js -> html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have an issue with mod_rewrite, I have a `.htaccess` file set up in directory called `cms`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on

#rewrite rules for edit
RewriteRule ^edit\/(.*) edit.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I would like to access it like so `sitename.com/cms/edit/2` but when I do I get errors:

[image: my errors to do with mime types]

When I access the natural path (`sitename/css/edit.php?page=2`) everything works fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you keep these rules? Moat likely in `.htaccess` .. but which folder -- website root folder or in `/cms/` subfolder?

Comment: Does `sitename.com/cms/edit/2` works (at least partially) or you just see an error and that's it?

Answer (score 1):

While this is an old issue, i just experienced the same thing but then when i used RewriteRules.

The solution for that turns out to be:

```
RewriteRule ^bower_components/(.*)\.(css) test/bower_components/$1.css [L,T=text/css]
RewriteRule ^bower_components/(.*)\.(js) test/bower_components/$1.js [L,T=application/javascript]
```

To force the type of the files you are rewriting. Targeting css + js specifically and forcing the T=<>

Comment: This should be the correct answer. In my case I couldnt alter the paths in the application because Im using a third party app. So I had to solve it in apache conf

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you had a typo, what about changing:

```
RewriteRule ^edit\/(.*) edit.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

To:

```
RewriteRule ^edit/(.*?)/?$ edit.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: My original rule only had one slash, I added it later to "escape" the slash to see if that would help, I also tried your version I get the same errors.  I even tried 

    RewriteRule ^edit/(.*?) edit.php?page=$1 [QSA,L] with no success.

I can access the page fine jus the MIME type errors are very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I know its old question, but just in case someone will still search for an answer.
I just witness same errors.

The deal is: with `L parameter mod_rewrite` will point request to the location you specified but all the ajax calls, includes, javascript src requests will behave as you where under original location.

Check the headers using LiveHeaders in Firefox for instance and you will see that your requests are pointing to wrong locations. I.e.: if in your play.php you link javascript like

```
src="myJS.js"
```

if `RewriteRule` points from

```
[siteroot]/play/some_data_here
```

to

```
[siteroot]/play.php?data=some_data_here
```

you will see that your play.php file will try to include `src="play/myJS.js"` which of course is not there so it returns `404` aka text/html.

In my case I 'fixed it' by adding R parameter so it redirects to new location. Down side of this is that address in the browser will change. Try changing `[QSA,L] to [QSA,L,R].`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem as well and found a solution.

If your css / js files are linked with a relative path, your RewriteRule will also affect them. To avoid this, reference the root directory. In other words:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

becomes

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```